# Checkbox list with Image

Tags: css, asp.net, checkbox, checkboxlist

I'm having problem with centering check symbol vertically. By default, it is located in the left bottom corner.

**This is how my checkboxlist look like:**
[image]

**and this is how I want it to look like:**
[image]

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="FoodCheckBoxList" runat="server" RepeatColumns="3" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
      <asp:ListItem> <img src="../images/foods/Food1.png" /> </asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem> <img src="../images/foods/Food2.png" /> </asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem> <img src="../images/foods/Food3.png" /> </asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem> <img src="../images/foods/Food4.png" /> </asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem> <img src="../images/foods/Food5.png" /> </asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem> <img src="../images/foods/Food6.png" /> </asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem> <img src="../images/foods/Food7.png" /> </asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem> <img src="../images/foods/Food8.png" /> </asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem> <img src="../images/foods/Food9.png" /> </asp:ListItem>
 </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Comment: post a fiddle with your code please.

Comment: try to set line-height for check box that equals to image height and give vertical-align:middle; if you can use css in your code

Comment: @Kiran, thank you for your reply. However, I tried this and no luck!
`.chkboxlist
        {
            line-height: 43px;
            vertical-align:middle;
        }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research i ended with this solution:

**html**

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="FoodCheckBoxList" runat="server" RepeatColumns="3" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" ClientIDMode="Static">
      <asp:ListItem> <img src="" style="width:128px;height:128px;background:blue" /> </asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem> <img src="" style="width:128px;height:128px;background:blue" /> </asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem> <img src="" style="width:128px;height:128px;background:blue" /> </asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem> <img src="" style="width:128px;height:128px;background:blue" /> </asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem> <img src="" style="width:128px;height:128px;background:blue" /> </asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem> <img src="" style="width:128px;height:128px;background:blue" /> </asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem> <img src="" style="width:128px;height:128px;background:blue" /> </asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem> <img src="" style="width:128px;height:128px;background:blue" /> </asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Don't blame me for inline style just use it instead of image.

**css**

```
    #FoodCheckBoxList [type="checkbox"] {
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    top: 70px;
    }

    label {
    display: block;
    padding-left: 35px;
    text-indent: -20px;
    }
```

Of course you can play with pixels to adjust it to your needs.

[image]

Comment: Didn't understand what you mean. Can you explain please?

Comment: People look for questions with accepted answers when they search on their problems. If you mark your answer as accepted, it will help future searchers to find the answer to their problem. You'll be able to mark your answer as accepted after 8 hours, I think.